# How do I get Pandas to read SPSS files?

Tags: python, pandas, spss

I tried using the `read_SPSS` command, but it didn't work.  The error seems to be telling me that I need `pyreadstat`, but I'm unable to even install that.  Why, though, would I need `pyreadstat`?  Isn't the ability to read `.sav` just built into Pandas these days?  I'm confused...

Here's the error text I get when I try using `read_SPSS`:

---

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-935d54be8b7a> in <module>
----> 1 twitter=pd.read_spss('twitter_study.sav')

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/spss.py in read_spss(path, usecols, convert_categoricals)
     34     DataFrame
     35     """
---> 36     pyreadstat = import_optional_dependency("pyreadstat")
     37 
     38     if usecols is not None:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/compat/_optional.py in import_optional_dependency(name, extra, raise_on_missing, on_version)
    108     except ImportError:
    109         if raise_on_missing:
--> 110             raise ImportError(msg) from None
    111         else:
    112             return None

ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'pyreadstat'.  Use pip or conda to install pyreadstat.
```

Answer (score 5):

What is built into `pandas.read_spss()` can be seen [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/spss.py).

The error message you are getting is a bit misleading as it suggests `pyreadstat` is optional, but the source code shows that `pandas.read_spss()` relies entirely on `pyreadstat`.

The easiest way to solve this would therefore be to install `pyreadstat`.

Comment: Thing is, as I said, I can't install pyreadstat.  I've tried doing it through both Anaconda and Pip, to no avail.  Any help here?

Comment: Another note, I can't even find pyreadstat in Anaconda Navigator as an uninstalled package.  What does this even mean?  Are there any workarounds here?

Comment: What error do you get when you try `pip install pyreadstat`?

Comment: The strange thing is, I don't even get an error.  I run pip or conda install through Terminal (I'm on a Mac) and nothing happens.

Comment: @RebelX0024 Using raw python installtion without anacond and installed the package with pip. I still get the same ImportError error.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are reading now, use

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyreadstat
```

it works well.

Comment: It was already answered that installing `pyreadstat` is a solution. Your way of installation should be a comment to the older answer, not a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, couldn't pip install or conda install, you can't find it through Anaconda Navigator and it's not listed here https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/

It got solved by running the following command mentioned by @埃塞ABELA in the **conda powershell prompt**

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyreadstat
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved by using these packages, try this command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyreadstat
```

If the above command does not work, try this instead:

```
conda install -c "conda-forge/label/cf202003" pyreadstat
```